# How to create a jquery script for counting the number of checkboxes ticked

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

[2]. So far I have written the following code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Check Box using jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form">
            <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="red" value="Red"/>Red
            <input type="checkbox" id="green" name="green" value="Green"/>Green
            <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="blue" value=" Blue"/>Blue
            <input type="checkbox" id="black" name="black" value="Black"/>Black<br/>
 </form>

<div id="result">0 boxes are checked</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="chkbox.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And now the script which I have written in the chkbox.js file is:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $checkboxes=$('#form td input[type="checkbox"]');
   $checkboxes.change(function(){
       var ccc=$checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
       $('span').text(ccc);
   });
});
```

I unable to figure out why this code is not working.

Comment: There are no `<td>` tags in your html, so `$('#form td input[type="checkbox"]')` won't find anything.

Comment: You don't have a table; why do you need `<td>` tags?

Comment: yes I dont have a table then what should I write in the chkbox.js file to count the number of checked boxes?

Comment: `<td>` tags are for tables. [See more information about tables here.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: Try just removing `td` from your selector.

Comment: @RobMoll I understood that but now in my case there are no tables so what should I write instead of  "$('#form td input[type="checkbox"]')" or what changes should I make inorder to make this work. Even after removing td from the selector its not counting. Please Help

Comment: You should really avoid jquery if possible. And as far as I can see you could just as well done this using querySelector to find the correct elements and DOMContentLoaded to run once the page has loaded.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not have `td` element inside the `#form` element, 2nd you're printing inside a generic `span` that doesn't exist. You could do something like this:

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="red" value="Red" /> Red
  <input type="checkbox" id="green" name="green" value="Green" /> Green
  <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="blue" value=" Blue" /> Blue
  <input type="checkbox" id="black" name="black" value="Black" /> Black
</form>
<div id="result">No boxes are checked</div>
```

And for your javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $checkboxes = $('#form input[type="checkbox"]');
  $checkboxes.change(function() {
    var nr = $('#form input:checked').length;
    var message =  (nr === 0)?'No':nr;
    message += (nr === 1)?" box is checked":" boxes are checked";
    $('#result').text(message);
  });
});
```

But, in general, study more about jquery, javascript and html.

Comment: Thankyou @Francesco Lisandro

Comment: I actually came accross one more error that when only 1 box is checked it should show "1 box is checked" instead of "1 boxes are checked" can you help me with the edits?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `td`s or `span`s in your code , check this simple way

```js
$('#form input.checkbox').click(function(){
  $('#result').text($('#form input.checkbox:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="red" name="red" value="Red"/>Red
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="green" name="green" value="Green"/>Green
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="blue" name="blue" value=" Blue"/>Blue
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="black" name="black" value="Black"/>Black<br/>
 </form>

<div><strong id="result">0</strong> boxes are checked</div>
```